# How to calculate and divide uniformly point around a circle?

Tags: c#, vector, draw, point, angle

Hello there everybody!

I'm trying to create a variable where you can put the number of points and the radius of a circle, and it will divide those points uniformly around the circle.
I'm trying to not use the Euler angles to set rotation or the Rotate or RotateAroundmethods.
But I am not having success...

These are how my code looks until the moment

```
public class PowerUps : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PowerUpPrefab;
    public GameObject Player;
    public int PowerUpCount = 3;
    public float PowerUpRadius = 1;
    public Vector3 newPowerupSpace;

    public GameObject[] SpawnPowerUps()
    {
        //get player positin
        Vector3 anchorPoint = Player.transform.position;

        GameObject[] SpawnPowerUps = new GameObject[PowerUpCount];
       

        float angleStep = Mathf.HalfToFloat((ushort)(360.0 / PowerUpCount));

        for (int i = 0; i < PowerUpCount; i++)
        {
            float theta = i * angleStep;
            newPowerupSpace.x = anchorPoint.x + (PowerUpRadius * Mathf.Cos(theta));
            newPowerupSpace.y = anchorPoint.y + (PowerUpRadius * Mathf.Sin(theta));


            SpawnPowerUps[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(PowerUpPrefab, newPowerupSpace, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Update:

I changed the

```
float angleStep = Mathf.HalfToFloat((ushort)(360.0 / PowerUpCount));
```

to

```
float angleStep = ((ushort)((360.0 / PowerUpCount) * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
```

and now is working.
I feel kind of stupid....

Update 2:
After doing some tests, I notice that some numbers don't divide uniformly across the circle. That's because I was converting de circle degrees to radium in the wrong part.
Here's how the code looks like now:

```
   public GameObject[] SpawnPowerUps()
    {
        Vector3 anchorPoint = Player.transform.position;
        GameObject[] SpawnPowerUps = new GameObject[PowerUpCount];

        float angleStep = ((ushort)(360.0 / PowerUpCount));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < PowerUpCount; i++)
        {
            float theta = i * angleStep;
            newPowerupSpace.x = anchorPoint.x + (PowerUpRadius * Mathf.Cos(theta * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
            newPowerupSpace.y = anchorPoint.y + (PowerUpRadius * Mathf.Sin(theta * Mathf.Deg2Rad));

        SpawnPowerUps[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(PowerUpPrefab, newPowerupSpace, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: *But I am not having success* - that's OK but we don't' know what success looks like, explain whats wrong?

Comment: [`Mathf.Cos(theta)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.mathf.cos?view=netcore-3.1) : _"x - An angle, **measured in radians**."_ See [Difference between radian and degree](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-radian-and-vs-degree/)

Comment: If you found a solution before you got answered or if your own solution seems better than any answer you got, it is [encouraged to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so it can be marked "answered". Unrelated to this: why not simply `Mathf.Cos( 2*Mathf.Pi / PowerUpCount )` ? And do not forget to check `PowerUpCount` for `0` ...

Answer (score 0):

To describe a circle in 3D it should have three parameters, Position, Radius and Normal. The normal can be used to create a transform from the unit circle to the 3D space. This example uses instance methods instead of static methods for cross/dot/normalization, but it should be trivial to translate to the unity3D conventions.

First we create an arbitrary vector that is orthogonal to the normal:

```
    public static Vector3 GetOrthogonal(this Vector3 self)
    {
        self = self.Normalized();
        if (Math.Abs(self.Dot(Vector3.UnitX)) > 0.9)
        {
            return self.Cross(Vector3.UnitY).Normalized();

        }
        return self.Cross(Vector3.UnitX).Normalized();
    }
```

We can then create two vectors that are orthogonal to the normal, and to each other:

```
        var xAxis = normal.GetOrthogonal();
        var yAxis = xAxis.Cross(normal).Normalized();
```

Getting the points is then simply multiplying each coordinate with the corresponding axis:

```
        var x = xAxis * (PowerUpRadius * Mathf.Cos(theta * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
        var y = yAxis * (PowerUpRadius * Mathf.Sin(theta * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
        newPowerupSpace = x + y + anchorPoint;
```

You could do the same by producing a transform matrix and transforming the 2D points. But this is fairly simple to do.